# Input field value from data table only can be stored when at the active page

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

View

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'storeID/'.$id)) !!}`

     @foreach($itemlist as $items)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! Form::text('max_' . $items->id,  old('max', $items->max_qty) !!}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-complete">Save</button>
```

Controller

```
public function storeItem(Request $request, $id_b)
  {
    $id = Prod::where('id_b', $id_b)->pluck('id_p')->toArray();
    foreach($id as $key => $val)
    {
        $max_qty = 'max_'.$val;

        $p = Prod::where('id_b', $id_b)->where('id_p', $val)->first();
        $p->max_qty = Input::get($max);
        $p->save();
      }
  }
}
```

JS

```
 $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
        var form = this;

        // Encode a set of form elements from all pages as an array of names and values
        var params = table.$('input,select,textarea').serializeArray();

        // Iterate over all form elements
        $.each(params, function(){
            // If element doesn't exist in DOM
            if(!$.contains(document, form[this.name])){
                // Create a hidden element
                $(form).append(
                    $('<input>')
                        .attr('type', 'hidden')
                        .attr('name', this.name)
                        .val(this.value)
                );
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to store the value of input field from data table into database, but it only allows to save the page where is active only, the other field value will became null. For example, there are 2 pages of data, i only allow to save the data on current active page, other pages value will get null. Any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: I am unable to understand your query, can you please provide a screenshot of your view (2 pages of data) here.

Comment: The problem is during submit, it only get the 10 data from 1st page and ignore the data from the other pages.

Comment: My query work fine, just the java script not working. Is there any mistake made by me?

Comment: Is this your full query or partial ???

Comment: full query, it can loop all the data and save but will save null value for the page 2 data because not get it during submit.

Comment: Try to serialize the from once again before submit, because elements are added dynamically so they might get lost while submition

Comment: sry, what do you mean by serialize agn?

Comment: you can't send this data using the normal submit button, You'll have to write a submit handler that serializes your data and sends it to the server.
Try to post the data to the server instead of normal submition

Comment: But it works when used with checkbox

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you. What works when used with checkbox

Comment: Mean that it works fine when used with checkbox to update item status. It can get every checkboxes data from the other pages as well. https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/#example1-code-html

Answer (score 0):

Your key for old() is incorrect:

```
<td>{!! Form::text('max_' . $items->id,  old('max', $items->max_qty) !!}</td>
```

Should be

```
<td>{!! Form::text('max_' . $items->id,  old('max_' . $items->id, $items->max_qty) !!}</td>
```

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely. By active do you mean the page currently displayed in the browser? Only the input in the form you submit will be sent to the server unless you're appending data via JavaScript post submission.

Comment: That should not be the issue, the issue is it only save the value for page 1 which currently displayed in the browser when there is another page of value will became null. So, when i click on submit, only page 1 value will be saved.

Comment: I append those value to hidden field but still the same, is there my controller got problem?